# Super Simple Visualization of moving objects

Tags: visualization

I am looking for an simple tool to make an even simpler visualization and maybe one of you knows a good tool.

Here is what i want to have:

A background image (in my case the layout of an warehouse) should be drawn all the time. Than i will produce a list of 8 x/y Coordinates (the 8 vehicles) every second and the program should place the pictures of the 8 vehicles to these positions accordingly. That's it.

Do you know a tool which can do this and for which I don't need much time to get into it?

Comment: Are you looking for an end-user application, or a library to develop this yourself? Is this some kind of diagramming application where you want the diagram to update in real-time as the data changes?

Answer (score 0):

You're intended application is not crystal clear. **My suggestion is to use HTML5 canvas on a simple web page.** Some advantages to using HTML5 canvas for simple visual tasks:

1. Accessible - web-based applications are easy to disseminate.
2. Maintainable - change your code and it can be reflected immediately in your client's browser.
3. Capability - there is experimental work to leverage clients' graphics cards so you can render 3D graphics, etc.
4. Popularity - there's a ton of support on the web for this emerging technology. You can easily get feedback on your code.

Here's a [great tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial) from the folks over at Mozilla, to get you started. Also a very cool list of demos at the bottom.